Does USPTO consider EU Registered Trademark as "First Business to Use"
Hi if a company from European union already have registered EU Trademark. Can another company from usa register same Trademark for USA market under similar category or USPTO would decline the application as Trademark is already registered in EU by someone else?
If USPTO allow the application and approve the Trademark to usa company for USA market. Can EU company later sue usa company on basis of "First Business to Use" and USA company's registered Trademark will be terminated.
Thanks

This question is similar to: International Trademark. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
